# My wallet won't connect to the daemon, re downloading doesn't help either. Can't reach my funds!

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monerod

The monerod crashes when I click it and the gui version tells me there is no connection daemon

Comment: Are you using the latest binaries from getmonero.org ? Which operating system are you using? If you're using Windows, you can open `%programdata%\bitmonero\bitmonero.log` and check for any relevant messages which could indicate what caused it to crash.

Comment: It says version 10.3.1 and yeah from getmonero.org the wolfram one. The log displays this which caught my eye... New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,stacktrace:INFO. I'm not very code savvy so I have no idea what to look for.

Comment: You could paste the monerod log somewhere so someone experienced can take a look. It's hard to troubleshoot with this much info. Also, which OS? 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: Who should I ask? Using windows 64

Comment: Try #monero on IRC (webchat: https://webchat.freenode.net)

Comment: Anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: @user3772: Try using a remote node -> https://moneroworld.com/#nodes

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if solution was found but mine was : 
- Delete the folder %programdata%\bitmonero
- Run monerod.exe
- then launch monero-wallet-gui.exe if needed

Hope it helps :)